# making app that add names with list view in kotlin

Tags: listview, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-adapter

i trying to make a simple app , that i can add names to the list view that i write in the plain text i made so the idea is when i click the button the name added to the list view with row number, i make this code but i don't know how to use button in the list view ! , even when i run the app its shows me white page

```
    package com.example.mylistviewexample

import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Layout
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
        listView.adapter = myCustomAdapter(this)


    }


    private class myCustomAdapter(context: Context):BaseAdapter() {


        private val names = R.id.nameText

        private val mContext: Context

        init {

            this.mContext = context
        }


            override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {

                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                val rowMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rows,parent,false)

                val countRow = rowMain.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rowNumber)
                countRow.text = "Row :$position"

                val nameText = rowMain.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name_textView)
                nameText.text = names.toString()

                return rowMain
            }

            override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {

                return "Test"
            }

            override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {

                return position.toLong()
            }

            override fun getCount(): Int {

                return count
            }


        }
    }
```

activity main

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="394dp"
        android:layout_height="545dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="105dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="93dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="  Add Your Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorHint="#E31313"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

rows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_textView"
        android:layout_width="239dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#0B0B0B"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.159"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"

        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_textView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code so you can see something happening inside the list you created.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
    listView.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, populateArrayList())
}

private fun populateArrayList() : ArrayList<String>{
    val myArrayList = ArrayList<String>()
    myArrayList.add("Luke")
    myArrayList.add("Anakin")
    myArrayList.add("Obi-Wan")
    myArrayList.add("Jarjar")
    return myArrayList
}

private class MyCustomAdapter(private val context: Context, private val myList: ArrayList<String>):BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
        val rowLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rows,parent,false)
        val countRow = rowLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rowNumber)
        val nameText = rowLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name_textView)
        nameText.text = myList[position]
        countRow.text = "Row :$position"
        return rowLayout
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return position
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }
}
```

}

You created a listview, but you didn't added anything inside of it, and every list needs to be populated with information for the viewports (every row you have); and for this in your adapter class you need should pass an ArrayList as a parameter for the construtor (private val myList).

Then you link every row to the position of the giving list.

I believe the thing you want to do is everytime you click the button you a new item will be added with the info you have in the edit text so create a onClickListener for your button and at each click you added it to your arraylist.